# Is there any default user login, other than usr: pi, pwd: raspberry?

Tags: raspbian, user

The reason I am asking is because I have setup my Raspberry Pi 3 b+ to run a specific script on boot, the only issue is this is an infinite loop and prints every time - so I cannot enter any commands!

At the moment I can interrupt with alt+f4 which brings me to the login. If I log in as the default user it just runs the loop again. Are there anymore default logins I can use to bypass this issue?

I know a better solution would be to edit the files from another PC however my machine's SD card reader is broken so I'll need an adapter...which I would like to avoid for now.

Comment: Remove the SD card. Edit the `cmdline.txt` and add ` init=/bin/sh` at the end of the one and only line in that file ... insert back into pi ... boot ... fix the issue ... reverse the process above

Comment: Other solutions may be available depending on how exactly you start the script and how exactly you log in.

Comment: In addition to what @JaromandaX said, use the opportuinty to also create a new user so you can login the next time.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the response, is this the only issue? My other machine is unable to read SD cards at the moment

Comment: `is this the only issue` I don't have an issue ... if you mean only solution, have you tried holding doing ctrl-c?

Comment: @JaromandaX ah sorry, meant solution. Yes only way of interrupting is to return to logon screen

Comment: in that case your only solution seems to be to edit the `cmdline.txt` - though, isnt' there a "safe" mode or something for the pi these days

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay as I thought no worries, thanks for the help!

Comment: It used to be that you could connect pins 5 and 6 on the gpio header and the pi would boot into "safe mode" - but, for some reason, that was removed many years ago - seems like an odd thing to remove though - best way to edit /boot/* files for fixing issues without needing to take the sd card out of the pi

Comment: @JaromandaX Perhaps you could summarise your comments as an answer and also clarify there is no other default login.

Comment: Well, maybe - I haven't asked if OP can use ssh at all :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have found holding ctrl+c works (it is tempormental and doesn't work everytime). If you put that as an answer i will mark correct

Comment: how about using ssh instead? unless you didn't enable ssh of course !!(I don't want to put in an answer for temperamental fixes :p )

Comment: How do you start the script on boot?